# How to use wildcards in a SQLite query?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to fetch data which contains specific string but query is not working, following is method for fetching data.

```
public Cursor getSearch(String item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String mQuery = "SELECT * FROM hadiths WHERE text LIKE %"+item.toString()+"%";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(mQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Logcat shows following error.

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM hadiths WHERE text LIKE %fast%

I know that the wildcard %% and string variable item is causing issue but how do I use string variable along with wildcard?

Comment: Use `Log.d()` to display the `mQuery`. If it's not obvious what is the problem after that, update your question with Logcat output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

As mentioned below by Jiří, parameters should be used to help prevent SQL injection issues.

In order to add parameters you could do something similar to this:

```
String mQuery = "SELECT * FROM hadiths WHERE text LIKE ?”;
String param1 = “%” + item + ”%”;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(mQuery, new String [] {param1});
```

In order to add another parameter:

```
String mQuery = "SELECT * FROM hadiths WHERE text LIKE ? AND Name = ?”;
String param1 = “%” + item + ”%”;
String param2 = name;

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(mQuery, new String [] {param1, param2});
```

This code is a bit cumbersome, but it is to illustrate that the parameters must be added in the order in which they are should be added to the query.

see SQLite documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase

---

**Original answer here for posterity. WARNING Dangerous SQL injection issue!**

You need to add single quotes to the query.

```
String mQuery = "SELECT * FROM hadiths WHERE text LIKE '%"+item+"%'";
```

Take a look at the SQLite docs:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Note:  There is no need to use `toString()` since "item" is already of type `String`.

Comment: But SQL injection right? I expected '?' in use, not a string concatenation... (though you can add those to the item such as `"SELECT... LIKE ?", (f"%{item}%",)`

Comment: @Jiří -- Thanks for keeping me honest! Indeed I posted a poor initial answer. I would say the SQLite Documentation should be a bit more cautious, too. Thanks again.

Comment: It depends. The documentation's purpose is not to inform the user about all possible threats and correct/incorrect uses. It would pollute the page and it would be hard to find the specific feature specs. The original answer was also safe unless the variable comes from a user: an unknown source. I just wanted to make a warning because many people go just CtrlC+V.